# TypeError DOMDocument::loadXML(): Argument #1 ($source) must be of type string, array given

Tags: php, laravel

Am new to laravel and here is the error i get immediately i login to the app.
https://flareapp.io/share/J7orgBGP#F47

Trying to develop a mobile topup app. badly need help with bypassing this error

Tying to edit the curl file but instead more errors

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), images are hard to read and troubleshoot. Please [edit] your post and add the code here as text. Be sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

From your stack trace, your request for `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard` successfully gets into `DashboardController::index()` method. So far so good.

But while preparing data for the view, esp, `User::getBalance()` causes an error.

In your getBalance() method, you have:

```
Curl::Make()->GET->url($this['reloadly_api_url']."/accounts/balance")->header([
            "Content-Type:application/json",
            "Authorization: Bearer ".Setting::get('reloadly_api_token')
        ])->execute();
```

During the `execute()` call, it misses the following part:

```
if (Helper::isJson($response)) {
    $response =  json_decode($response, true, 512, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
}
```

If their `Helper::isJson($response)` has no problem, the problem should be on the response from your `[reloadly_api_url]/accounts/balance`

NOTE
It must be a json encoded `string` so it can be decoded by `json_decode()`

From your error message, the response is an `array`, not a `string`.

You need to modify the response from `[reloadly_api_url]/accounts/balance` to a string.

I guess you can wrap the return of `[reloadly_api_url]/accounts/balance` with `json_encode()`